# getElementById to select class instead of id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a bit of jQuery that outputs some HTML to an id, however in my code it must output to a class. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=output;

<div class="content> </div>
```

I've tried getElementsByClass but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It's all well explained in the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there isn't jquery, it's raw JS and if you already have jQuery in your project, it's a bit easier with jQuery:

```
$(".content").html(output);
```

Comment: Why not complete the answer with `.html(output)`?

Comment: Honestly - my wife started talking to me... will update.

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns an array, so assuming this is the first content in your document, use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].innerHTML = output;
```

If there are more than one element, you'd use a loop to loop through them and target the element you wish, e.g

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[1].innerHTML = "Second element with class content";
    content[3].innerHTML = "Fourth element with class content";
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Y3FM/1/)

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked but Jim W's answer was more suitable for my code.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array of all matching elements. Try looping through this array and adjusting each array item

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name');
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ )
{
elements[i].innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: There is no `document.getElementsByClass()`.

Comment: that is so true, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` for this purpose

```
document.querySelectorAll(".content")[0].innerHTML = output;
```

`documet.querySelectorAll` returns the elements with matching selectors.

Comment: Why use `"div.content"` instead of just `".content"`?

Comment: It would be more specific as the class `.content` is using on `div` tag, is not good practice?

Comment: I know it would be more specific, but the OP didn't say that was required and lots of people seem to like to just stick it in, but if not required (which it almost never is) all it does is make more work for the query engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the getElementsByClassName method.

[0] is missed in the javascript. Thats  the reason , you are not able fetch the records.

document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].innerHTML = output;